# Is there any difference between `def self.myMethod` and `def myMethod`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby and ROR at the same time and noticed one thing in someone else's code. Sometimes I see methods being defined in these two apparently slightly different ways:

```
class SomeClass < SomeInheritance::Base

  def self.myMethod
  end

  def myOtherMethod
  end

end
```

Does it make any difference? I mean, does the use of `self` in a method definition affects the way the method works somehow? Any enlightenment is welcome.

Comment: nope, self. makes it a class level method whereas without self, its an instance method. So the 'self.' one can be invoked as SomeClass.myMethod whereas the other one would need an instance of SomeClass

Comment: I recommend you to watch http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4

Comment: First hit on google (for me at least) for `ruby method definition self`: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`def self.method_name` will define a class method rather than an instance method - as will

`class << self; def foo; end; end`

A good post on the topic is [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) from Yehuda Katz

**for example:**

```
class Foo
    def method_1
       "called from instance"
    end

    def self.method_2
       "called from class"
    end

    class << self
       def method_3
         "also called from class"
       end
    end
end

> Foo.method_1
NoMethodError: undefined method 'method_1' for Foo:Class

> Foo.method_2
 => "called from class" 

> Foo.method_3
 => "also called from class" 

> f = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x10dfe3a40> 

> f.method_1
 => "called from instance"  

> f.method_2
NoMethodError: undefined method 'method_2' for #<Foo:0x10dfe3a40>

> f.method_3
NoMethodError: undefined method 'method_3' for #<Foo:0x10dfe3a40>
```

Comment: So `method_2` and `method_3` are just like static methods?

Comment: +1 nice answer:  An example is worth a 1000 words of explanation.

Comment: @marcioAlmada - it behaves like a static method.  Foo is an object (just like f), and method_2 is a method defined in Foo's (meta)class.  Read the linked post for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this code:

```
class SomeClass
  p self
end
```

you will get 'SomeClass' printed. That's because `self` refers to the SomeClass object (yes, clases are objects in Ruby too).

With self, you can define a class_method, i.e. **a method on the class object** (although it's actually defined in the object's metaclass...):

```
class SomeClass
  def self.class_method
    puts "I'm a class method"
  end

  def instance_method
    puts "I'm an instance method"
  end
end

SomeClass.class_method  # I'm a class method
```

There's much more to know about Ruby object model. Dave Thomas gave an excellent talk on this subject - see the link @Octopus-Paul recommended to you.

Comment: already knew `self` was just like `this` from other languages, just didn't figured out it was used to declare the class methods (equivalent to static methods in other languages). +1

Comment: @marcioAlmada `self` actually changes its meaning depending on the context :) - once you understand `self`, then you understand Ruby object model...